# How do I get this non-scaled image to look "sharp"?

Tags: unity

I am using a 1920x1080 resolution. For the boxes at the bottom of the image posted below, the one on the left uses a 64x64 pixel sprite (which is the exact size it needs to be without scaling it up or down for) and the boxes on the right use a 128x128 pixel image which is twice the size of how many pixels represented in the scene.

I would expect that the smaller image that I do not scale looks more "crisp", while the larger image that I scale looks more blurry.

It is not what I get.

How do I get the smaller image to look "sharp"?

[image: 64x64 box vs 128x128 box]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using pixel perfect snapping? Show us the configuration of your sprite material, sprite renderer or UI image, canvas and/or camera as applicable.

Comment: I think my issue has to deal with using vector graphics(illustrator).

Comment: You've shown us your texture import settings, which is not what I asked to see. If you think this could be a problem with your source asset files, you should show us those assets too.

Comment: Switching from Bilinear to Point filtering helped

Comment: That suggests it may be a pixel snapping issue. Do you get different results if you tick the "Pixel Snap" checkbox in your sprite material?

Comment: You are correct.  Bilinear Filtering + Pixel Snapping produces a sharp image for the 64x64 thank you much.  I am curious as to why this is not default for the standard sprite shader?

Comment: It's only applicable if you're making a pixel perfect game, which comes with extra restrictions on your supported resolutions and such that Unity does not impose unless you opt-in. It can also make movements slightly less smooth, since you're limited to full-pixel intervals, without using interpolation to blend sub-pixel movement. In any case, if you've solved your problem, want to post your solution as an Answer?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'pixel perfect game'.  I am not making a pixel art game just trying to get the sharpest looking sprites that I can.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. If you're not able to find a satisfactory definition of pixel perfect online, then you are welcome to post a new question asking for clarification about this common term.

Answer (score 1):

Bilinear Filtering + Pixel Snapping produces a sharp image for the 64x64.